# Characterisation of Hochschild Cohomology and semi-simple representation

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, group-schemes

in Demazure-Gabriel "Introduction to Algebraic Geometry and Algebraic Groups" II, §3, 3.7 (Proposition), I do not understand why the implication (iii) -> (i) follows from the result 3.3:
The statement in 3.7 is "All representations of the group scheme G are semi-simple" -> "for all representations, the n-th Hochschild cohomology group is 0 for $n>0$".

The proof only stats that this follows directly from the statement "the functor $V \rightarrow H^n(G,V)$ is the derived functor of $V \rightarrow V^G$.

I have no idea why this is a complete proof. Any help and or idea is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If every $G$-representation is semi-simple, then every short exact sequence of $G$-representations splits. This implies that the functor $V\mapsto V^G$ is exact (in fact, every additive functor is exact). Therefore, the higher derived functors $V\mapsto H^n(G,V)$ vanish for $n>0$.

Comment: I've already seen the converse of your first statement (i.e. if every s.e.s. of G-representations splits, then every rep. is semi-simple). How do you prove the opposite? Do you need some kind of Schur's lemma? Furthermore, why does every s.e.s splitting imply that the functor is additive?

Comment: The semi-simplicity is indeed equivalent to the statement that every short exact sequence splits. But I cannot give you a proof unless you tell me your definition of semi-simple.

Comment: I never claimed that every functor is additive. I just stated that, if every short exact sequence splits, then every additive functor is exact.

Comment: I use the definition that a representation is semi-simple if it is the direct sum of irreducible representations (which is defined as not having a proper subrepresentation)

Comment: Why does every representation splitting imply that the functor is exact? (or in other words: Why is the fixed-point functor additive?)

Comment: Ok. Then you need Zorn's lemma to show that if $V$ is semisimple, then every subrepresentation $U \subseteq V$ admits a complement, that is, there exists a subrepresentation $W\subseteq V$ such that $V = U\oplus W$. See for example [here](https://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M250.04/semisimple.html), where this is proved for semi-simple modules over a ring, but the argument is the same.

Comment: If you have an additive functor $F$, then $F(U\oplus V) = F(U)\oplus F(V)$ canonically. Thus, given any split short exact sequence $0 \to U \to U\oplus V\to V\to 0$, applying $F$ yields the sequence $0\to F(U) \to F(U)\oplus F(V) \to F(V)\to 0$, where the first map is the inclusion and the second is the projection; this sequence is exact by inspection. Hence $F$ is exact.

Comment: thanks! Maybe I didn't frame my question the right way: I am still wondering why (1) Every representation is semi-simple implies every short exact sequence splits (my idea: if I have $0 \rightarrow V' \rightarrow V \rightarrow V''$ with $f: V' \rightarrow V$, then $V/V' = V''$ by 1st iso theorem. $f(V')$ is a subrepresentation of V (maybe?) and thus there is $W''$ such that $V = f(V') \oplus W''$. By 2nd iso theorem $V/V' = ( f(V') \oplus W'') / V' = W''$ and thus $W'' = V''$. Therefore, $V' \oplus V'' = V$).

Comment: and (2) Why is the fixed-point functor additive?

Comment: Your suggested proof is correct. You should try to answer question (2) yourself. There is really no idea needed.